# Utilizacion de una BDD u otra, dependiendo de como corro mi API

Tags: javascript, sql-server, nodejs, express, testing

Estoy realizando testing en una api. Pero estoy buscando la manera de que, en base a como corro el proyecto me guarde los datos en una base u en otra(si corro con 'npm run dev': me lo guarda en la bdd de producción. Si corro con 'npm run test': me guarda los datos en la bdd de testing). Lo que se me ocurrió es que en base al script que ejecuto para correr el proyecto, me guarde en una variable el true y despues en el config modificar los datos de conexión con un condicional dependiendo de lo que haya en la variable, anteriormente mencionada.
Yo vi en un video de youtube que hacian algo parecido pero con mongoDB y no lo pude aplicar. Yo estoy utilizando SQLServer.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: HolaJuan, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Answer (score 1):

Tuve que descargar la dependencia de dotenv-save, si mal no recuerdo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el mismo script para correr con testing o en producción coloque el nombre de la variable que contienen el el nombre de la base de datos y lo cambie por el nombre de la base de datos que necesitaba usar, cada vez que corriese el proyecto con ese script.

Si ven el valor de test:watch se entiende mejor lo que quiero explicar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el .env Entonces use en el script el nombre de la otra base para modificarlo en el .env y que entre en la otra base de datos.